# Multiple file upload in PHP - rename files

Tags: php, file, file-upload, rename

I'm a beginner in php and now doing a project in php. I want to upload images(maximum four image files only).I used the following code to upload images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
count=1;
function add_file_field()
{
if(count<4)
{
var container=document.getElementById('file_container');
var file_field=document.createElement('input');
file_field.name='images[]';
file_field.type='file';
container.appendChild(file_field);
var br_field=document.createElement('br');
container.appendChild(br_field);
count++;
}
}

</script>



        <div id="file_container">
    <input name="images[]" type="file" id="file[]" />
<br />
    </div> 

        <br><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="add_file_field();">Add</a>
```

I used the following code for single file upload.It's working

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "File Error : " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}else {
echo "Upload File Name: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "File Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "File Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />"; 
 echo "File Description:: ".$_POST['description']."<br />";

 if (file_exists("images/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
 {
 echo "<b>".$_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. </b>";
 }else
 {

$tmpname=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$new="jun.jpg";
rename($name,$new);
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/".$new);
  echo "Stored in: " . "images/" .$new."<br />";
 ?>
 Uploaded File:<br>
 <img src="images/<?php echo $new; ?>" alt="Image path Invalid" >
<?php
}
}
}else
{
echo "Invalid file detail ::<br> file type ::".$_FILES["file"]["type"]." , file size:::       ".$_FILES["file"]["size"];
}
?>
```

I need help to modify this code to upload maximum of 4 images.
Can rename function be used to rename a selected file for upload on moving to a specified folder?
but it was showing error

Please do help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $count=count($_FILES["images"]["name"]);


for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{   
  if ((($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i] == "image/gif")
 || ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i]  == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i]  == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i] < 100000))
{

 if ($_FILES["images"]["error"][$i]  > 0)
 {
 echo "File Error : " . $_FILES["images"]["error"][$i]  . "<br />";
  }
  else 
 {
  echo "Upload File Name: " . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i]  . "<br />";
 echo "File Type: " . $_FILES["images"]["type"][$i]  . "<br />";
  echo "File Size: " . ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i]  / 1024) . " Kb<br />"; 

   if (file_exists("public/images/".$_FILES["images"]["name"][$i] ))
  {
   echo "<b>".$_FILES["images"]["name"][$i]  . " already exists. </b>";
   }
   else
  {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$i] ,"public/images/".             $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i] );
    echo "Stored in: " . "public/images/" . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i] ."<br />";
   ?>
   Uploaded File:<br>
   <img src="public/images/<?php echo $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i] ; ?>" alt="Image path    Invalid" >
  <?php
  }
  }
  }else
 {
  echo "Invalid file detail ::<br> file type ::".$_FILES["images"]["type"][$i] ." ,    file    size::: ".$_FILES["images"]["size"][$i] ;
  } 
}
   }?>
```

image uploaded using for loop..foreach was showing error

Answer (score 3):

You should allow multiple file selection in your file input, so you do not have to add a new input over and over again:

`<input id="file" type="file" name="images[]" multiple>`

After submitting the form you can iterate over `$_FILES` array like that:

```
foreach($_FILES['images'] as $file) {
    //your code here --> replace $_FILES['file'] with $file
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I changed my code because you have to use `images` as a key though. If it does not help to describe your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of multi-file upload in PHP

https://github.com/hemantrai88/html5-php_multi-file-upload

Comment: do understand the question before answering and read FAQ before answering,only sharing links is not a good answer, you describe what is happening there, to consider this as answer.

Comment: The example is pretty self-explanatory. It uses PHP and HTML to upload multiple files with a basic UI showing all files listed for upload and their upload status after submitting the form. Minor changes might be required to get it working for any custom requirement. By default, this example is best-suited for pop-up upload forms.

Answer (score 0):

I have one example which is working, I think this will help you

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

In php

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $query="INSERT into upload_data (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
        $desired_dir="user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         mysql_query($query);           
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
```